# iphone: strace, dtruss, dtrace or equivalent?

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, strace, dtrace, ltrace

Does anyone know if there is something like `strace`, `dtruss`, or `dtrace` for iPhone?

```sh
tester-iPhone:/tmp root$ apt-cache search dtruss
tester-iPhone:/tmp root$ apt-cache search dtrace
tester-iPhone:/tmp root$ apt-cache search trace
tester-iPhone:/tmp root$ apt-get install strace
```

> ```sh
> Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree
> Reading state information... Done
> E: Couldn't find package strace
> ```

```sh
tester-iPhone:/tmp root$ apt-get install dtrace
```

> ```sh
> Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree
> Reading state information... Done
> E: Couldn't find package dtrace
> ```

```sh
tester-iPhone:/tmp root$ apt-get install ltrace
```

> ```sh
> Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree
> Reading state information... Done
> E: Couldn't find package ltrace
> ```

```sh
tester-iPhone:/tmp root$ apt-get install dtruss
```

> ```sh
> Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree
> Reading state information... Done
> E: Couldn't find package dtruss
> ```

Answer (score 1):

DTrace (and therefore dtruss too) have apparently been ported to iOS a while ago, but Apple have not released it outside of their own labs. The best reference I can dig up is a quote from one of the authors of DTrace: https://twitter.com/ahl/status/311866307115098112

Answer (score 1):

The [Frida](http://www.frida.re/) framework may be useful, which provides for dynamic code instrumentation using a Python API. It lets you inject snippets of JavaScript into native apps on iOS (and Windows, Mac, Linux).

There's a good tutorial on using [Frida on iOS](http://www.frida.re/docs/ios/).

There's also Saurik's [Cycript](http://www.cycript.org/) which allows for 'developers to explore and modify running applications on either iOS or Mac OS X using a hybrid of Objective-C++ and JavaScript syntax through an interactive console'.

And of course there's his [Cydia Substrate](http://www.cydiasubstrate.com/) allows one to alter/inject the behaviour of iOS apps.

Comment: hmm... this is interesting. Does it related to DBI(Dynamic Binary Instrumentation)?

Comment: it seems related to DBI Tools like Pin, DynamicRIO or TEMU but not exactly strace. Anyway, thanks for useful informations.

Comment: Yeah true it's is a PIN-like tool and not quite s/d/trace, but since they're not available it seems to provide the closest related functionality - I think one could instrument the functions one is interested in to provide for similar analysis.

Answer (score 1):

On a real iOS jailbroken device I used `frida-trace`.

```
frida-trace -m "+[NSUUID UUID]" -U "Debug CrackMe"    // trace UUID
frida-trace -m "*[ComVendorDebugger* *]" -U -f com.robot.demo.app   // wildcard trace on Classes
frida-trace -i "getaddrinfo" -i "SSLSetSessionOption" -U -f com.robot.demo.app      // trace SSL setup options on iOS
frida-trace -m "-[NSURLRequest initWithURL:]" -U -f funky-chicken.hello-swift-4-2      // trace URLs
```

This tool also works on `jailed` devices.  Refer to `frida-gadget`.

On an iOS simulator I could `dtrace` calls:

```
sudo dtrace -qn 'syscall::ptrace:entry { printf("%s(%d, %d, %d, %d) from %s\n", probefunc, arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3, execname); }'
Password: // you need sudo


ptrace(31, 0, 0, 0) from debugger_challen
```